# why the double for loop here for recursion?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

```py
def diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s):
    result = []
    if "+" not in s and "-" not in s and "*" not in s:
        result.append(int(s))

    for i in range(len(s)):
        char = s[i]
        if not char.isdigit():
            leftPart = diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s[0:i])
            rightPart = diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s[i+1:])

            for part1 in leftPart:  #<---- 
                for part2 in rightPart:   #<-----
                    if char == "+":
                        result.append(part1 + part2)
                    elif char == "-":
                        result.append(part1 - part2)
                    elif char == "*":
                        result.append(part1 * part2)
    return result

def main():
    print("Expression evaluations: " + str(diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression("2*3-4-5")))

main()
```

This code takes a string of numbers and operations and prints out every possible value that it can. For example 2*(3-(4-5)) = 8

I have tried to draw this out on paper to see what the recursion is doing but for the life of me I do not understand why this has to do the double for loop as indicated in the code. What exactly are they doing and why do I get a different answer if I do the following (to me they seem like they do the same thing):

```py
def diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s):
    result = []
    if "+" not in s and "-" not in s and "*" not in s:
        result.append(int(s))

    for i in range(len(s)):
        char = s[i]
        if not char.isdigit():
            leftPart = diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s[0:i])
            rightPart = diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression(s[i+1:])


            if char == "+":
                result.append(leftPart[0] + rightPart[0])
            elif char == "-":
                result.append(leftPart[0] - rightPart[0])
            elif char == "*":
                result.append(leftPart[0] * rightPart[0])
    return result


def main():
    print("Expression evaluations: " + str(diff_ways_to_evaluate_expression("2*3-4-5")))

main()
```

Answer is wrong but aren't they doing the same thing? What is the double for loop doing exactly?

Comment: It's combining all ways of evaluating the left hand side with all ways of evaluating the right hand side in all possible ways.  Ex: 1+2+3*3+4+5 when the current separating op is the *. The left hand side can be 3 or 5. The right hand side can be 7 or 9. Those are returned by the recursive calls. So there are four possible results: 3*7, 3*9, 5*7, 5*9.  The double for loop is finding those  final values.

Comment: You should maybe give feedback to answers to your previous questions. You never come back to them; never accept an answer. I don't think any one will be motivated to answer your questions like this.

Comment: My apologies, I will from now on and I have done it for your helpful explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this example:

```
2*3-4-5+6*7
```

The outer loop is intended for picking one operator out of those five operators. The first operator we find is at `i==1`. But let's focus on what happens when `i==5`. Two recursive calls are made:

- One for `2*3-4`
- One for `5+6*7`

Now let's for a moment *assume* that those recursive calls do their jobs correctly, so then we get back:

- `leftPart=[-2, 2]` because we can do `2*(3-4)` or `(2*3)-4`.
- `rightPart=[47, 77]` because we can do `5+(6*7)` or `(5+6)*7`.

With `i==5` we have the `-` operator. Since we have 2 ways to calculate the left side of it, and 2 ways to calculate the right side of it, we have in total 2x2=4 possibilities on how to apply this center `-` operator:

Two possibilities when we choose `2*(3-4)` on the left side; varying the right side:

- `(2*(3-4))-(5+(6*7))`
- `(2*(3-4))-((5+6)*7)`

...and two more when we choose `(2*3)-4` on the left side, again varying the right side:

- `(2*3)-4)-(5+(6*7))`
- `(2*3)-4)-((5+6)*7)`

This is exactly what the double for-loops are doing: iterate the possibilities at the left side, and for each of those iterate the possibilities at the right side.

In the malfunctioning version of the code, you would only consider the first possibility at the left (using `leftPart[0]`), and the first possibility at the right (using `leftPart[0]`), and ignore all combinations that involve other entries in either `leftPart` or `rightPart`.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for your explanation! I understand now.